# how to model the below transformation

Tags: clojure

I have a hashmap of data with the key a string description and value an integer weight.

`{:a 2 :b 3 ......}`

I need to  transform the hash into a vector of vectors. Each internal vector contains the map entries.

`[[[:a  2][:b 3]...][......]]`

each internal vector is built based upon some rules. Ex the sum of all weights should not exceed a certain value

Normally this seems to be a good case for a reduce  where a hash is transformed into a vector of vectors of map entries. However I may need to iterate over the hash more than once as I may need to reshuffle the entries between the internal vectors so that all of the vectors sum up to a certain num.

Any suggestions on how the problem should me modelled?

Answer (score 0):

Well,  for  starters,  Clojure  maps  are  already  sequences  of  vectors.  So  no `reduce`  needed:

```
=> (for [e {:a 1 :b 2}] e)
([:a 1] [:b 2])
```

Instead of  thinking of it as "iterating,"  you  should  take the  approach of  defining a  function  that  takes  your  input  vectors and  returns a  new  sequence with the  adjustment.  Recursively call  this  function  until  the  sum  you  need  is  reached.